# Mirror One Repository Into Another Existing Repository

Tags: git, github, mirror

Can I mirror a repository (let's call it repo A) that I worked on into another already-existing repository (let's call this one repo B)? I want to keep repo A and its history, and mirror code from repo A into repo B (which exists but does not have any pertinent code yet). Bonus if I can pick specific files to copy from repo A.

I know I could manually copy the code from repo A into my text editor and paste it into new files in repo B, or I could delete repo B and rename repo A, but I would prefer to keep both repositories and mirror repo A using git.

Comment: You can set up multiple remote repos with `git remote`, and merge or cherry-pick between them.